# SwiftUI: enable watch digital crown via focus change

Tags: swift, swiftui, watchkit, apple-watch, watchos

I want to provide a button that will enable the Apple Watch digital crown for input. That involves ensuring something has focus that will get the crown changes. I've got a little tester for this:

[image: Apple Watch Screen Shot]

When you touch the "Enable Crown" button, I want to start getting crown changes.

Here is code I created:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var crownValue = 0.0
    @Namespace private var namespace
    @Environment(\.resetFocus) var resetFocus
    @State var forceFocus = false
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            VStack {
                Button("Button") {
                }
                .focusable(forceFocus)
                .prefersDefaultFocus(true, in: namespace)
                Text("\(crownValue)")
            }
            .digitalCrownRotation($crownValue)
            
            // Goal is for this button to give focus to other button and start capturing
            // digital crown changes; but have to touch this button twice to get desired
            // effect
            Button("Enable Crown") {
                print("Enabling crown")
                forceFocus = true
                resetFocus(in: namespace)
            }
        }
        .focusScope(namespace)
    }
}
```

It works, but only if I touch the "Enable Crown" button twice!

Any idea how to achieve my goal? The complete source code to this example is at https://github.com/t9mike/DigitalCrownHelp2.

Answer (score 2):

I was over complicating this. The following works fine, keeping focus on the button that is used to enable the crown feature:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var crownValue = 0.0
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView {
            Text("\(crownValue)")

            Button("Enable Crown") {
                print("Enabling crown")
            }
            .focusable()
        }
        .digitalCrownRotation($crownValue)
    }
}
```